# Cant connect to Ejabberd on docker using ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ejabberd

I'm trying to run the ejabberd docker container and when I run it I can't connect to it.

```
$ sudo docker run --restart=always --name ejabberd -d -p 5222:5222 -p 5280:5280 -p 5269:5269 ejabberd/ecs
```

```
$netstat -an | grep LIST
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

Any idea why docker isn't opening the ports on the host?

Comment: Try running without `-d` flag. This will let you know if container has exitedd or if there are any errors. Use `sudo docker run --restart=always --name ejabberd -p 5222:5222 -p 5280:5280 -p 5269:5269 ejabberd/ecs`

Comment: Thanks, I can connect to the admin webpage, but when I try to use Adium to register a user, it doesn't connect. Although the ports seem to be open.

Although I only see "virtual hosts" option in the admin webpage but no hosts and I can't add anything or something.